# How does one create a set of 3-tuples in Elm meeting a given condition?

Tags: signals, elm

I know that Elm has neither for-loops (no surprise) nor comprehensions (mildly surprising). I know that `map` is to be used where one might expect comprehensions.

But how would you build a set of 3-tuples from three range variables? I'm interested in producing these tuples, which is trivial to produce in Python:

```
>>> [(x,y,z) for z in range(5) for y in range(z) for x in range(y)]
[(0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 4), (0, 2, 4), 
(1, 2, 4), (0, 3, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]
```

I'm not sure how to produce this in Elm. This is what I have tried:

```
import Text (asText)
import List (map)
main =
  asText <| map (\z -> map (\y -> map (\x -> (x,y,z)) [0..y-1]) [0..z-1]) [0..4]
```

This produces

```
[[],[[]],[[],[(0,1,2)]],[[],[(0,1,3)],[(0,2,3),(1,2,3)]],
[[],[(0,1,4)],[(0,2,4),(1,2,4)],[(0,3,4),(1,3,4),(2,3,4)]]]
```

which is close but needs flattening.

I'm new to Elm so I don't know the proper way to generate these tuples. I could probably figure out how to flatten the lists I came up with, the code itself seems rather verbose (should I use `List.map3` instead?) and for large number ranges I would want to generate the values on demand. Is there a way to generate the values as a signal, perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Flattening

The minimal changes to make your example work the way you want is to change the outer two `map` with `concatMap`:

```
import Text (asText)
import List (map,concatMap)
main =
  asText <| concatMap (\z -> concatMap (\y -> map (\x -> (x,y,z)) [0..y-1]) [0..z-1]) [0..4]
```

Depending on how you like to read code, you may prefer this:

```
import Text (asText)
import List (map,concatMap)

list = 
  [0..4] |> concatMap (\z -> 
    [0..z-1] |> concatMap (\y -> 
      [0..y-1] |> map (\x -> (x,y,z))))

main =
  asText list
```

This is actually not something you can do with `map3`, because that only works for lists that aren't dependent on each other.

## Generate on demand

Signals are probably not handy for generating on demand. Unless there is an obvious time component involved, and even then if the list ends signals are not the right choice.

To generate something you should define a lazy sequence. You can use functions to model laziness or use the [Lazy library](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/maxsnew/lazy/latest/) if you want to memoize the lazy actions.

To create you own lazy sequence, just use something like:

```
type LazySeq a = End | Item a (() -> LazySeq a)

map : (a -> b) -> LazySeq a -> LazySeq b
map f ls =
  case ls of
    End -> End
    Item i next -> Item (f i) (\() -> map f (next ()))

append : LazySeq a -> LazySeq a -> LazySeq a
append l r =
  case l of
    End -> r
    Item i next -> Item i (\() -> append (next ()) r)

concat : LazySeq (LazySeq a) -> LazySeq a
concat ls =
  case ls of
    End -> End
    Item i next ->
      case i of
        End -> concat (next ())
        Item i2 next2 -> Item i2 (\() -> append (next2 ()) (concat (next ())))

concatMap : (a -> LazySeq b) -> LazySeq a -> LazySeq b
concatMap f ls =
  concat (map f ls)
```